# Meaning of "out of an interest"

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning, idiom-meaning

In the following [YouTube](https://youtu.be/m3yVCHj3jA8?t=4m37s) video, (4:35) entitled:
*Master Craftsman, Nathie Katzoff | HUMAN*, I heard

> I didn't get into this out of an interest in capitalism. I got into it **out of an interest** in craft.

I searched "out of an interest" in the following dictionaries, but failed to find the meaning.

- Oxford Dictionaries Online (ODO)
- Merriam-Webster (MW)
- American Heritage Dictionary of the English Language
- Cambridge Dictionaries Online (CDO)

What does the "I got into it out of an interest in craft." mean?

Is this replaceable with "I found an interest in craft."?

Comment: [*"out of interest"* definition](https://www.google.co.uk/#q=%22out+of+interest%22+definition)

Comment: @sevenOfNine Do you understand what 'to get into [something]' means?  If not - you can look it up in a dictionary too.  Then "I got into it out of an interest in craft." will make perfect sense.

Comment: I find it weird that ELL migrated this here, seems like the kind of question they tackle daily. But anyway: "I got into it": *I developed an interest in* or *I got involved with*; "out of": *due to*; "an interest in craft": *a different and preexisting interest*. Whatever *this* is, the author is involved, engaged, or interested in it, not because he cares about capitalism (which either you'd assume or he's being accused of), but because he's interested in craft.

Comment: @DanBron It says it came from *meta* - not from ELL.

Comment: @TrevorD Ah, good eye. That makes a lot more sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sentence conveying that, the person already has interest in craft. So, he got into it.

Or we can consider it as *as a matter of interest*. Sounds, both *found interest* and *Already has interest, so chosen it* are correct.